# Why does as.POSIXct return NA for some date-times that should be correct?

Tags: r, datetime

Hi my data and formats seem to be correct, but some times it just doesn't work. Here's a example hopefully reproducible:

```
df = data.frame(t = c("2011-05-26 17:40:43", "2014-03-09 02:34:54"))
df
#                     t
# 1 2011-05-26 17:40:43
# 2 2014-03-09 02:34:54
df$t = strptime(df$t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
df
#                     t
# 1 2011-05-26 17:40:43
# 2 2014-03-09 02:34:54
df$t = as.POSIXct(df$t)
df
#                     t
# 1 2011-05-26 17:40:43
# 2                <NA>
```

Any help's appreciated.

---

update: should be related to DST. I tested with other dates of DST

```
df = data.frame(t = c("2011-05-26 17:40:43", "2013-03-10 02:34:54", "2014-03-09 02:34:54", "2015-03-08 02:34:54"))
df
#                     t
# 1 2011-05-26 17:40:43
# 2 2013-03-10 02:34:54
# 3 2014-03-09 02:34:54
# 4 2015-03-08 02:34:54
df$t = strptime(df$t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
df
#                     t
# 1 2011-05-26 17:40:43
# 2 2013-03-10 02:34:54
# 3 2014-03-09 02:34:54
# 4 2015-03-08 02:34:54
df$t = as.POSIXct(df$t)
df
#                     t
# 1 2011-05-26 17:40:43
# 2                <NA>
# 3                <NA>
# 4                <NA>
```

Comment: I cannot replicate on R version `3.2.2` running on Linux.

Comment: Nor can I on 3.2.1. You might want to restart your R session and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks guys~ I'm using 3.2.1 in windows, and have restarted R couple times...

Comment: By chance, do you have DST in your time zone? Did it occur on 9 March, 2014?

Comment: hey @Pascal! Yes that day was DST day! And I tested with other DST days and they all have this problem

Comment: Hi @Pascal thanks a lot! do you know how people usually deal with this? The data isn't even Eestern daylight-saving time...

Comment: Did you try to play with the `tz` argument of `as.POSIXct`? My time zone doesn't have DST.

Comment: I added `as.POSIXct(df$t, tz='America/New_York', usetz=T)` and it's still NA. Do you mean I should treat my data in a time frame of, like Beijing time, which doesn't use DST? @Pascal

Comment: I am not sure if it is a problem related to your locale or to Windows. On my Linux machine (my time zone has no DST), I get `"2011-05-26 18:40:43 EDT" "2013-03-10 03:34:54 EDT" "2014-03-09 03:34:54 EDT" "2015-03-08 03:34:54 EDT"` utilizing `as.POSIXct(df$t, tz='America/New_York', usetz=TRUE)`.

Comment: Use `as.POSIXct(df$t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = "GMT")` with the original characters, i.e., don't use `strptime` in between.

Comment: Hi Roland thanks a lot. Using `tz = "GMT"`, both `strptime` and `as.POSIXct` works

Answer (score 2):

If the time does not exist in your timezone due to DST-time changes this is more or less expected behaviour as the help of `strptime` says.

> Remember that in most time zones some times do not occur and some occur twice because of transitions to/from ‘daylight saving’ (also known as ‘summer’) time. strptime does not validate such times (it does not assume a specific time zone), but conversion by as.POSIXct will do so. Conversion by strftime and formatting/printing uses OS facilities and may return nonsensical results for non-existent times at DST transitions.

Since strptime uses the system libraries it is also to be expected that the result differs on Linux and Windows.

In my experience using libraries like lubridate yields more predictable results.